# .NET - Content-Disposition Header Not Showing in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm trying to create a WebAPI that will make a GET request to another server (enterprise Oracle Agile PLM), and return a document. I'm using .NET 4.5.1. I've been able to get the actual file data, but having a hard time getting the original filename for it. I've read that the Content-Disposition header of the response is the best place to look for this, as it isn't included in the URI.

Here's what I'm currently trying and failing with. This is way incomplete now that I'm purely focused on trying to get the header to show:

```
public string GetDocsForDocNumber()
    {
        var docUrlString = "https://agprd.myDomain.com/Agile/link/Information%20Systems/1044698/files/ALL";
        var username = "user";
        var password = "pass";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(docUrlString);
        try
        {
            string authKey = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)); 
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authKey);

            //DEBUG - Printing out all request headers...
            WebHeaderCollection whCollection2 = request.Headers;
            for (int i = 0; i < whCollection2.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n REQUEST header key: " + whCollection2.GetKey(i) + "    value: " + whCollection2.Get(i));
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream rstream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                //DEBUG -- Printing out all response headers...
                WebHeaderCollection whCollection = res.Headers;
                for (int i = 0; i < whCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("header key: " + whCollection.GetKey(i) + "    value: " + whCollection.Get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }
            res.Close();
        }
        catch { }

        return "blah";
    }
```

Here are the headers that get printed in VS:

```
 REQUEST header key: Authorization    value: Basic eWFAKeJaSEHnef2jk9hasE=  (this is fudged FYI)

 RESPONSE header key: Transfer-Encoding    value: chunked

 RESPONSE header key: Cache-Control    value: private

 RESPONSE header key: Content-Type    value: application/octet-stream

 RESPONSE header key: Date    value: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 18:38:15 GMT

 RESPONSE header key: Set-Cookie    value: JSESSIONID=GTF8bn1XvKPw1mQ1HJaejfejjaE3fNb0pTG5T15VVbwGlQ!331878993!-1921346355; path=/; HttpOnly,NSC_WTWS-BHQSE-443=ffffffffaf1cef7b419874afe8455e445a4a422d69;Version=1;path=/;secure

 RESPONSE header key: X-Powered-By    value: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
```

I've tried similar things using WebClient, HTTPClient, etc and can't get this to show up. If I take that URI and plug it into my browser, here's what the response header shows:

[Browser response header pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83RiE.png)

I don't understand why it's not there when I make the request from the WebAPI. I can make the same request from an iOS app and it works fine. Again, I can get the actual document data just fine, but I'm not able to get the filename because that header is MIA.

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to this, so I'm hoping it's something dumb and easy.

Thanks

Comment: Now since I don't know really what is going on with the oracle side, this could very well be wrong. But the reason I think the content disposition header isn't present is because there is code on the oracle side checking for a request header like `user-agent`, and since you don't have one it figures out that you are not a browser. (The `Content-disposition` header hints to a browser how to treat the received data, so it is probably assuming you don't need that header there). So you could test this theory by adding a `user-agent` header (with the value of a valid user agent) to your request .

Comment: @pidizzle LOL you are the man! That did the trick! It's Friday afternoon, so my beer is already open, but I'm dedicating the rest of it to you! Cheers & thank you!

Comment: Haha that made me laugh. Enjoy that beer of yours and this weekend! I posted an answer so you could mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle server is only sending the `content-disposition` when there is a valid `user-agent` present (browsers automatically send a user-agent header). The oracle server probably does this because it assumes that you wouldn't want the `content-disposition` header unless you are a browser (browsers use the `content-disposition` header to know how to treat certain data coming back. i.e download this file, display this image, etc.).

So add the `user-agent` header yourself to get the `content-disposition` header back.